# GWT 2.1 Cell Widgets - continuous scrolling

Tags: gwt, widget, cell

To me it seems like the new GWT 2.1 table widget (as well as the other ones) is missing a continous scrolling feature (simmilar to smartgwt's "live grid"). Overriding the AbstractPager seems to be a long way to go.

Any ideas how to implement it as easy as possible?

Thanks, Mario.

Comment: Nice, someone else is struggling with this.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this example](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList) and its source code. Hope this somehow helps.

Comment: This type of scrolling does not really help. I was trying to achieve something more like this: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#featured_grid_live. When user is scrolling I am putting two DIVs and one FlexTable between them into a ScrollPanel. Then I only adjust the size of DIVs so the table appears in the ScrollPanel's window. My point was that instead of trying to display complex tables with too many rows at once (can be achieved with GWT cell widgets) it is better to fetch only currently displayed rows on demand.